# Image Dodging (color matching algorithm) in ERDAS

Tags: mosaic, erdas-imagine, image-mosaic, atmospheric-correction

I have two LISS 3 images acquired in Feb and March a year apart. I have performed atmospheric correction (haze reduction) for both the images individually before applying the color matching algorithm while mosaicing. I applied the image dodging color matching algorithm in the mosaicpro tool. The output was fine, except that the edges of the two images seemed to be lightened, i.e., the mosaic was not seamless in the edges. It could be a radiometric error for the edges of the two images. I could not find any specific parameters in the tool to overcome this error.

I have tried this procedure (color matching two images before mosaicing) in ArcGIS and ENVI but the results were not satisfactory.

Can I overcome this error using ERDAS?

[image: This is the output I have got]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect is very likely due to surface bidirectional effect, which generally causes high reflection at large view angle. You can use a brdf model to correct it such as Walthall model.

Answer (score 0):

In order to eliminate this issue you have to use seamline, Keep in mind while editing seamline try to digitized the seamline in center of common overlap area. The outer edge will be lightened.There is a way to overcome the edge lightened problem too. Approached is different need some manipulation

Comment: I used the seamline option to generate the above mosaic image. But the lightened edges did not get eliminated. I am not sure what approach you are referring to , to overcome this error.